# after substr i got non numeric value error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with `non-numeric value encountered` error in this function
and my `$phone`'s value is `123243743`

```
private function _validatePhone($phone){
    $subhp="";
    if(substr($phone,0,3) =="+62"){
        $subhp += substr($phone, 3,strlen($phone)-1);
    }elseif(substr($phone,0,2)=="62"){
        $subhp += substr($phone, 2,strlen($phone)-1);
    }else{
        $subhp += substr($phone, 1,strlen($phone)-1);
    }
    var_dump($subhp);die();
    $nohp = "0".$subhp;
    log_message("info","validate phone to be ".$nohp);
    return $nohp;
}
```

After i substr'ed the `$phone`, the non numeric value error is showing up. I already searching the solution for days but i can't find the solution.

Comment: Why are you using `+=` to "add" a substring result to an empty string..... `+` is numeric addition; `.=` for string concatenation would be more appropriate for strings.... don't treat phone numbers as numbers; they aren't, they're strings

Comment: That's right... Concatenation operator is dot, not plus

Comment: yeah i'm sorry, i am still amateur at php, thankyouuu for the solution @MarkBaker

Comment: yes thankyouuu @Jean-LucAubert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you did too much JavaScript.

InPHP, the string concatenation operator is `.`, not `+`, so in order to append a string to another, you must use `.=` instead of `+=`.

Moreover, since all these concatenations happen in a `if/elseif/else` structure and your string is empty before that, you don't need to concatenate at all, a good old assignation will me enough :

```
private function _validatePhone($phone) {
    if (substr($phone, 0, 3) == '+62') {
        $phone_offset = 3;
    } elseif (substr($phone, 0, 2) == "62") {
        $phone_offset = 2;
    } else {
        $phone_offset = 1;
    }
    $subhp = substr($phone, $phone_offset, strlen($phone) - 1);
    var_dump($subhp);die();
    $nohp = "0$subhp";
    log_message('info', "validate phone to be $nohp");
    return $nohp;
}
```

I also took the liberty to *standardize* your code so that it's easier to read and therefore maintain. You should know that double quotes take more time (7 times if I'm not mistaken) to process than simple quotes because PHP will look for variables between them, so I replaced them by double quotes except when there were variables to put in it concatenated to the string.

I also extracted `$subhp`'s assignation from the `if/elseif/else` structure so that it will be more manageable to update that line.

Comment: really thankyou sir for the solution and stardadized it ! really grateful